# JSDoc throws error while generating document if ES6 arrow functions used

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, jsdoc

I've written stateless component and declared Props outside component. When I try to generate `jsdoc` throwing error.

```
MyComponent.js

/**
 * 
 * Custom Props for title and data array
 */

type Props = {
      title: string,
      data: Array<Object>
      };

const MyComponent = ({ title, data }: Props) => {

  const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value).reverse();

  return (
      <div>
        //...
      </div>
     );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

jsdoc command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc ./src/MyComponent.js
```

Error:

> Unexpected token, expected ;  (19:5)

Need help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you certain that the problem is specific to arrows? There's a bunch of stuff that may not be supported - types, JSX. Any way, it doesn't seem like a good idea to generate from `src`.

Comment: Actually, I'm generating a doc from a different path not directly under src. I've put it just for an example :)

Comment: I agree with estus. In addition, a quick google turns up jsdoc-jsx, which is either a plugin or fork (Im sorry, I don't know) that should do what you want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-jsx

Comment: @GrahamPHeath still not working. throwing error on import statement